# IntelliJ auto replace double-quoted strings

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for Angular 6 (Typescript) development. When new import is added automatically by IntelliJ it's always double-quoted string.
There is possibility to change it to single-quoted manually:
[image: exemplary screenshot]

However, I wish it would happen automatically and by default. How to set it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In intellij settings you can change this.

Go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Typescript**. And then in the **Punctuation** tab change the use **Double** quotes always to **Single** quotes.  Refer the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do this for Python (PyCharm)

Go to **Settings** -> **Intentions**. Under the **Python** section un-check `Convert single-quoted to double-quoted strings and vice versa`

[image]