# Disable IntelliJ auto replace double quotes with single quotes

Tags: intellij-idea, lua

I found a thread for someone using IntelliJ and editing Typescript files.

[IntelliJ auto replace double-quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535910/intellij-auto-replace-double-quoted-strings)

However, those options do not exist in my version when editing Lua.

How do I prevent or disable the auto formatting of nit picky things I don't care about. I don't want it to replace double quotes with single quotes.

local returnData = {["avgPrice"] = nil, ["numSales"] = nil, ["numDays"] = 10000, ["numItems"] = nil, ["craftCost"] = nil}

Take that line for example. I don't want CTRL + ALT + L I don't want that to be changed to this

local returnData = {['avgPrice'] = nil, ['numSales'] = nil, ['numDays'] = 10000, ['numItems'] = nil, ['craftCost'] = nil}

Likewise I don't like any automation. So also even when I type if I have a contraction like You've I know I need two single quotes. I don't want IntelliJ to do it for me. So the string "you''ve" I want to type that myself or I want the program to error if I forget.

How do I prevent these kinds of things from happening?

[image: My Version]
[image: reformat code]
[image: Settings]

Comment: Please submit a ticket to *Lua* plugin vendor, https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/issues

Comment: Even if I use EmmyLua?

Comment: report it to https://github.com/EmmyLua/IntelliJ-EmmyLua/issues then:)